# Automatically populating default issue fields?

Tags: jira, jira-zephyr

We are working on transitioning to [Zephyr for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.je) from HP QC/QTP; but a tiny wiggle has presented itself:

When creating a new issue from a test run; the tester has to manually enter version info for the new defect, which on its own is fine, but it's an additional step, and on occasion forgotten.

What we would like then, is for the field "Affects Version/s" to be automatically filled based on either the state of the project, or the sepcific values set in fields in the test.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Allright. You can add custom javascript to JIRA by going to **JIRA Administration -> System -> User Interface -> Announcement Banner**.

The easiest way is to add a  tag linking to your javascript file (wherever it is, must be available to all users. Preferably on the same server as your JIRA installation or a public domain).

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://YOUR_JIRA_SERVER/includes/custom/javascript/custom.js"></script>
```

If you add it like above, go into your JIRA installation into the **atlassian-jira/includes/** folder and add a folder called **custom** within which you add another folder called **javascript** and create a file called **custom.js**.

In that file, add the following code:

```
AJS.$(document).ready(function()
{
    AJS.$(document.body).on('change', '#issuetype-field', function()
        {
            var issuetype = AJS.$(this).val();
            if(issuetype === "Test")                //Might want to change this!
            {
                AJS.$("#fixVersions").val(17403);   //Might want to change this!
            }
        });
});
```

This will add an eventlistener to the issuetype-field input found in the create modal window in JIRA. When it changes (which it automatically does on load, then on every user select) it check its value to see if it's Test and if so changes the fixVersion input to a whatever you want to set it to (change this to match your own preferences).

Using jQuery with jira is a bit tricky, you need to use the AJS object to access the jQuery object (more information here: https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/applicationHeader.html).

The two parts you need to change are the actual names and values of your issuetype and your fix version (use firebug or your browsers equivalent to get this).

I've tried this and it worked well! Good luck!